# Ajax POST to Backend Using React Router and Express

Tags: ajax, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am trying to submit a simple form in a React component:

```
class UploadPartList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [] };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Clicking submit');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/partListUpload",
      success: function(){
        console.log("Post success");
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>

          <form id="csvForm" action='' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method='post' encType="multipart/form-data">
            <p>upload your part number list (.xls or .csv)</p>
            <input id="uploadCSV" type="file" name="csv_form" />
            <input type="submit" className="submitButton" />
          </form>

        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

My routes.js file is thus:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/App';

const Routes = (props) => (
  <Router {...props}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </Router>
);

export default Routes;
```

And my Express routes in the server are defined like this:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.use('/partListUpload', upload.single('csv_form'), partListUploadController);

app.post('/partListUpload', function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.body);
});
```

However, when I try to submit the form, I receive a 404 error. It seems that React expects the route defined by React Router instead of a route I define in my server.

I have looked over similar StackOverflow questions and haven't found a solution that works. How can I hit a route I define on the backend?

Comment: Is that url in your Ajax call definitely correct relative to the root of your application?

Comment: In addition to the URL in the example, I have tried "../partListUpload" and "../../partListUpload". Neither work. In all three cases the console logs the message "POST http://localhost:3000/partListUpload 404 (Not Found)", which seems to indicate that they are all trying the same URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my problem was that my Express server was not actually running. I created this app using the [create react app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) package. I then followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@patriciolpezjuri/using-create-react-app-with-react-router-express-js-8fa658bf892d#.l3k61lbe2) in setting it up with Express. However, I continued trying to get my app to work by just running *npm start* in the CLI instead of *npm run build* and then *node server/index.js*. Now it works.

Comment: I have the same problem now. I use npm start and commented out all the express route code and everything works but file upload doesn't. Do you need the express routes? Mine seems to do nothing? Also I can't figure out how to write the file to server. Can you share partListUploadController code?

Comment: I actually ultimately could not get it to work with partListUploadController. Since the route itself did not have a great of middleware, I just put it in the server file directly. Try something like this:  
  
`const referenceDBParse = require('../models/referenceDBParse'); `

then 
  
`app.post('/referenceUpload', upload.single('reference_form'), 
referenceDBParse.parseReference, function(req, res) {  
  res.redirect('/adminDashboard');  
});`
  
My code has changed significantly since I originally posted this, but this route illustrates the point well.